# Does NSURLSession use any network traffic while idle?

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsurlsession

If I use an NSURLSession to download some files and once they are complete I just leave it sitting there idle (rather than invalidating it), does it consume any network traffic keeping a connection to the server open? In other words should I invalidate it and create a new one next time I need to download or just keep leave it idle waiting to be used again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll be safe idling it. If you don't initiate a task, it shouldn't cause any traffic.